# QzhbCgiParse API not working

Tags: cgi, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to use QzhbCgiParse API in RPGLE to parse the QUERY_STRING, but it keeps throwing the error '**Error code parameter not valid**'.

```
 Dcl-Pr QzhbCgiParse extproc('QzhbCgiParse');  

    cmdStr  char(100) const;   

    outFmt  char(8) const;                     

    targetBuf char(5000);                

    targetSize int(10) const;                  

    responseLen int(10);                 

    errorCode likeds(WPError);                 

 End-Pr;                                       

 Dcl-S  cmdStr  char(100);  

 Dcl-S  outFmt  char(8);   

 Dcl-S  targetBuf char(5000);

 Dcl-S  targetSize int(10);

 Dcl-S  responseLen int(10);

 Dcl-Ds WPError;         

   bytesProv int(10) inz(%size(WPError)); 

   bytesAvail int(10) inz(0);   

   errMsgId char(7);     

   *n char(1);          

   errMsgData char(40);    

End-Ds;            

QzhbCgiParse('-v ':'CGII0100': targetBuf: %size(targetBuf) : responseLen :WPError);
```

I have tried many data structure for the error code parameter, all in vain. Please advise.

Comment: How did you define the prototype for `QzhbCgiParse()`?

Comment: I have included the prototype. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working, API prototype was the issue. Once i changed the prototype as below, it worked perfectly.

```
Dcl-Pr QzhbCgiParse extproc('QzhbCgiParse');
 cmdStr  char(65535) const;               
 outFmt  char(8) const;                   
 targetBuf char(65535);                   
 targetSize int(10) const;                
 responseLen int(10);                     
 errorCode char(56);                      
End-Pr;
```

Comment: for `cmdStr` you probably want `options(*string: *trim: *varsize)`, and for `targetBuf` you probably want `options(*varsize)`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions